# What are some other sentences with the same meaning as "I'm calling in regards to a laptop I recently purchased."

Tags: grammar, word-order

I'm struggling to come up with any other sentences that inform the listener at the other end of the phone of the reason for the call; so, any sentence of the form "I'm calling ... [reason]". The main sentence format I'm interested to know is the one with the word "concern". I'd appreciate it if you could educate me on this type of sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm calling **about** a laptop I purchased.

This is probably the most informal way to say it, although it isn't generally considered rude. [See (preposition) definition 4.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/about)

> I'm calling **concerning** a laptop I purchased.

This is slightly more formal than "about" but fundamentally means the exact same thing.

Your example sentence sounds fine in normal speech too, although it is a fair bit more formal than the other two. It's also more commonly heard as "**with** regards to" rather than "in regards to", although I've heard both. "Regarding" also works.

Comment: I would question the use of **with regards to** in the plural. In the sense of**concerning**, the phrase would be **with regard to** in the singular. **With regards to** might be used in an entirely different context, as in signing off a letter: **With (my fondest) regards to the family....** https://writingexplained.org/with-regard-to-or-with-regards-to